# PHP skip items of array within another array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

all

I have an array list in which i have cities name
and
in second array list i have cities name that i wanna show them as checked items.

What i'm trying to do is below

```
<?php

$mainArr = array("New York", "LA", "London", "Tokyo", "Paris", "Rome");

$checkedArr = array("New York", "Tokyo");

foreach( $mainArr as $main ) 
{
   foreach( $checkedArr as $check ) {
     if( $check == $main ) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="$main" checked />', $main;
      }else {
         echo '<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="$main" />', $main;
      }
   }
} 
?>
```

But this show duplicate values . How do i get rid of this ? I dont want repeated values.

New york and tokyo should be shown be checked
and
the rest should be same.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know of `in_array`? http://ro1.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use in_array:

```
foreach($mainArr as $main) {
    if (in_array($main, $checkedArr)) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="$main" checked />', $main;
    } 
    else {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="$main" />', $main;
    }
}
```

A bit shorter without code duplication:

```
foreach($mainArr as $main) {
    $checked = in_array($main, $checkArr) ? 'checked' : '' ;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="city" value="'.$main.'" '.$checked.' /> '.$main;
}
```